# How to get the value from influx db using time string

Tags: node.js, influxdb

How to fetch the data from influx db using time-string in node.js

Query:

```
"SELECT * FROM Measurement WHERE time > '2018-01-08 23:00:01.232000000' AND time < '2018-01-09'/ "
```

I am facing the following error when executing the above query

```
Error: Error from InfluxDB: invalid operation: time and *influxql.RegexLiteral are not compatible at ResultError.Error
```

Comment: I'm not fluent in node, so please pardon the possibly silly question: what's the trailing "/" for? InfluxDB interprets that as the start or end of a regular expression (regex). Is there a way to not include it?

Comment: I could able to fetch the data from influxdb.